# drawback in using array as parameter?

Tags: javascript, php

I always use one array arguments to a function whenever I need more then 3 parameter.

Example: Consider a function call like this.

`processSecondStage($stepTitle, $round, $entryId, $formId, $stepType, $stepAfterApproved,  $assigneees, $stageToMove);`

I always prefer the below one.

`processSecondStage(array(
  'stepTitle'         => $title,
  'round'             => $round,
  'stepAfterApproved' => $stepAfterApproved,
  'entryId'           => $_entryId, 
  'assigneees'        => (array)$_POST['flow-asignee'],
  'stageToMove'       => $currentStep,
  'formId'            => $targetFormId, 
  'stepType'          => 'approval'
));`

Advantage (I might be wrong):

a) Can add more number of parameter

b) Readability

c) Order can be changed easily

d) Default parameter handling is easier

Disadvantage :

a) Code length is increase specially in case when we have less then 3-4 arguments.

Can anyone please help me Know more disadvantage of using the array parameter ?

Whenever I change other developer code (like I am going to do now), then I feel that there are some major disadvantage of using `array` as parameter because if that was not the case then it should have been a standard practice.

Although I have given example of PHP, but I find this in other language also on which I work.

Thank You.

Comment: You lose static analysis don't you? It will fail at runtime instead of compile time if a bad key is passed.

Comment: @Carcigenicate yes that is a valid point for compiled languages.

Comment: I believe the two programming patterns you could apply here are: command pattern which in turn would suggest the builder pattern, to validate all necessary parameters are provided. The drawback of arrays as parameters: no code completion, no type hints (yeah, even in php), hell of a documentation necessary, it's unclear what parameters are needed. Technically it might not seem necessary, but it *might* improve tool-support and ease stuff for whoever has to adopt your codebase. Languages that allow named parameters in function callsusually don't suffer as hard from this ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Arrays are useful as a parameter when things you want to pass are closely related and do not make sense separately. A classical example is a `Color` that is defined by `blue`, `green`, `red` (and maybe `gamma`). Combining these parameters into an array (or object in javascript) allows you to swap it out easily.

Always using an array as the single parameter of a function makes you loose out on a parameter list an IDE can give you. For someone reading the code, it is quite a hell to figure out what needs to be passed to a function. It also opens the door to future creep (oh, this function was only making me coffee, but if I add another optional parameter it can also make me tea. Oh, and maybe I can let it make me dinner to. Why not add the functionality to order an attack helicopter too).

In a regular parameter list you can pass things by reference (`function pushElement(array &$sortableArray, $element)`). This is not expected in a regular array, if it is even possible.

The point about default values is kind of a moot point. Normal parameter lists allow type hinting and default values just fine:

```
function action(string $action = 'tickle', string $target = 'Polar bear') {
  print "I {$action} a {$target}";
}
```

A single parameter as array probably only really shines when passing some kind of static configuration. You keep the configuration of something separate from the actual code using it, making it easier to modify the configuration. At the same time you leverage the fact that you do not have to send 20 parameters in a very specific order.

---

In your case the parameter list you give is wildly varied and long, which suggests that your function is doing way too much. Part of it should probably be moved to a constructor and part of it should probably be moved to some kind of `Form` class.

Answer (score 1):

Parts of the topic are very much opinionated...

The problem you describe is not just parameters as a list vs a sequence of parameters. There are several problems that occur (with both in your example).

- Tooling
- Ordering of parameters
- Semantics

**Tooling** is probably obvious: If you have only arrays as parameters, no IDE will know what is supposed to be inside. Okay, *most* IDEs won't know.

**Ordering of parameters** is usually dictated by the name of the function and/or its semantics. If you `drawLine` the canonical order of the parameters is `($from, $to)`. If there is no canonical order, there might be something else wrong with the code... (see below)

**Semantics**: If you have 3+ parameters (especially if you have way more), it is very likely, that the abstraction is *wrong*. For example let's assume you have a function `createShirt($size="m", int $red, int $blue, int $green, Image $logo, $material="wool")`: The order of attributes is arbitrary and the object produced (a shirt) may not need all of those parameters, but you can absolutely use this abstraction. I would much prefer the builder pattern, example:

```
$shirt = ShirtBuilder::create("m") // verifies m is a size
      ->setColor(new Color($red,$green,$blue)) // has type-hint color
      ->setImage($logo) // has type-hint
      ->setMaterial($material)
      ->build();
```

It absolutely is more verbose, but it is apparent you only have to call functions that are needed, you can validate set values at any point (read: function call). The build function could verify that the combination is valid and the Shirt object itself could even be immutable.

However, arrays absolutely *do* have their place and purpose. But usually it is "providing a list of things of the same type". If your array has only string-keys that are from a very small domain, you *probably* want an object.

Using objects will trigger questions such as "which parameters should belong to this object?". if there is no semantic reason for a true subset of parameters to appear together, you probably want the command pattern (command objects). and IDEs might provide all the wonders that make using those easy

tl;dr:

Using arrays to hold a list of heterogeneous parameters is probably an anti-pattern (might be warranted in some scenario/language).

Functions/methods with more than 3 parameters *suggest* too little abstraction (there might be reasons). Use appropriate design patterns.